# weighted distribution hash bits

Tags: hash, cryptography, md5, hashcode, cryptographic-hash-function

I would like to ask, if there is weight distribution equation for hash function or not?

like in channel coding theory there was weight enumerator equation for reed-solmon which give you the number of words of wight i.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean cryptographic hash function, then certainly not. Ideally cryptographic hash function can have any value, so every word of a given length is possible under a cryptographic hash function. 
Reed-Solomon codes are linear codes, and the minimal weight of each word is the distance of the code, and it is in no way similar to a hash function.

Comment: that's right, but i think there must be probability equation which determine the weight of hash digest?

Comment: No, that would mean the hash function is bad. If probabilities would not be equal for every digest, then it would be easier to find collisions for some of them, and that goes against the definition of cryptograhic hash function.

Comment: I think the answer is true, give me a few minutes to think about!